# Finding $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\int_{-1}^1\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\lim_{t\to0}\int_{-1}^1\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\mathrm dx=??$$

Since the limits of the integral are constants,

$$L=\lim_{t\to0}\int_{-1}^1\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^1 \lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\mathrm dx=0$$

But evaluating the integral first,

$$L=\lim_{t\to0}2\arctan\left(\frac1t\right)=\text{d.n.e}$$

I do not have enough knowledge to understand the convergence theorems. My professor just told us that the limit and integral can be interchanged if the limits of integration are constants. Why does this not apply here? Is there a simple reason behind this?

Comment: "The limit and integral can be interchanged if the limits of integration are constants." This is simply false, as we have many counter-examples (including your example). There is a couple of well-known sufficient conditions that guarantees the interchanging the limit and integral, such as the monotone convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem, but none of them applies to your case (and they shouldn't).

Comment: @SangchulLee understood. I shall wait till I have enough knowledge to actually learn those theorems.

Comment: The limit within the integral is also a bit weird. Note that $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{x^2 + t^2} = 0$$ only holds for $x \neq 0$. For $x = 0$, the limit does not exist.